# How to disable cell editing of a Jtable displayed from a result set

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, resultset

Hi guys i am having issues trying to disable editing for a table after displaying it. i would have used setEnabled but i still want the table to be clickable because i am displaying and editing the content of it's rows with the help of text fields.

i have searched and got hints that i have to override isCellEditable() or use DefaultTableModel. However, the major problem now is that my table is displayed using rs2xml because i am actually loading contents of a database table into the JTable. here is the segment of my code that displays the table from a result set:

```
         do {
                //get the table...
                attendanceTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(
            } while (rs2.next());
```

rs2 is my result set.

i tried using default table model... i tried something like this:

```
          do {                  
             DefaultTableModel myTable = (DefaultTableModel)attendanceTable.getModel();
              myTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
             } while (rs2.next());
```

but gave me errors because there was no setModel method under defaultTableModel. that was what i understood by using defaultTableModel...

about overriding isCellEditable(), someone that asked a similar question (but without displaying table with rs2xml) mentioned that doing that also made it impossible for his program to edit the table.

please guys i really need help with this...thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i have searched and got hints that i have to override isCellEditable()

Good advice.

> However, the major problem now is that my table is displayed using rs2xml because i am actually loading contents of a database table into the JTable

Why is that a problem? You can override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the JTable.

Also, why does you code have a `do...while` loop? You only create one TableModel for the JTable. The DBUtils code will do the looping to read all the data from the ResultSet and create the TableModel.

Comment: thanks sir for the hint about the do...while loop. Now when creating the isCellEditable() method, please is it better to create it under a DefaultTableModel or directly under the table. i have seen two examples like that. but my problem now is that my table and all gui components around it was created with netbeans and i cant edit the initializing code i guess.

Comment: @spynoble, why are you talking about a DefaultTableModel? You are using DBUtils which returns you a TableModel so you can't override any of its methods. I don't use an IDE, so I can't advise you how to extend a class in Netbeans, although I'm sure that is possible in the IDE or the IDE would not be very useful. My advice is to not use the IDE. Instead create the GUI code yourself and just use the IDE to debug the code. Spend your time learning Java, not the IDE.

Comment: sorry sir i was able to edit the initializing code thus `qualTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
    },
    new String [] {
        "Qualifications", "Year attained"
    }
) {
    };
    @ Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }
});` however the problem still persisted. so i am having a feeling that whenever i use that DbUtils stuff it sort of overrides what ever setting i have used on my JTable. please sir any hints?

Comment: so that means i have to live with whatever DBUtils gives me?

Comment: If you want to use DBUtils then yes you use the TableModel that the method returns. But as I already stated you can override the `isCellEditable(..)` method of the JTable. Or you don't have to use DBUtils, you can just load the data directly into a DefaultTableModel yourself. See the `TableFromDatabaseExample.java` code from [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for a simple example of how this might be done.

Answer (score 2):

> ...trying to disable editing for a table after displaying it. i would have used setEnabled but i still want the table to be clickable because i am displaying and editing the content of it's rows with the help of text fields.

Overriding `isCellEditable()` should not disable clicking on a cell or selecting a cell. It just prevents the cell from being edited.

> i have searched and got hints that i have to override isCellEditable() or use DefaultTableModel. However, the major problem now is that my table is displayed using rs2xml because i am actually loading contents of a database table into the JTable.

This should have no bearing on whether or not you can override and disable editing.

> here is the segment of my code that displays the table from a result set:...

Snippets don't help much. Post a [minimal code example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, one without need of a database.

> i tried using default table model... i tried something like this:

This code makes no sense to me, mainly because you're creating a DefaultTableModel object and then promptly ignoring it -- why? Then you're using a class, DbUtils, that we have no knowledge of and so can't help you with.

> about overriding isCellEditable(), someone that asked a similar question (but without displaying table with rs2xml) mentioned that doing that also made it impossible for his program to edit the table.

That's about all the help I can give other than to direct you to the tutorials and ask for more and better information and code.